# Intel's IPP to create images from arrays

Tags: arrays, image, visual-c++, intel, intel-ipp

I am working in C++ and I have a vector container of float values. I want to write an image file to disk where the pixel values of the image are the values from the array.For instance I have 40,000 values in my array and I want a 200x200 image file to be created in some format(the format is not very important, however, I would prefer something with lossless coding if possible). I would like to do this using Intel's libraries, IPP. Can somebody tell me which function would be most appropriate for my problem.(At present I'm sticking only to grayscale images.)

Comment: something like matrix?

Comment: I'm not sure I got you. Yes, the data is in the form of a matrix. I have to write it out as a grayscale image using Ipp

Comment: if i found anything related to your question i will post here

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to just write it out as space delimited numbers in a file.raw, and load it with ImageJ. ImageJ will give you an option to specify width, height and bit-depth. 
Second, one I have dome in the past, is (if you use Matlab too), use matlab engine commands to figure(data), and then used getframe/get(gcf) etc. to imwrite it to your fav. image format (Matlab has tons of them)

Comment: The original poster is not using Matlab, just as a heads up. She appears to be using C++.